# C++ variable is not a type name

Tags: lamp, generated

Hey I just took out this: point from the class and it is giving me this lamp symbol can someone explain to me what I can do

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead, copy and paste your code into the question and format it so that it's readable.

Comment: Have you tried placing the mouse over the lamp?